# Is my understanding correct about web APIs

Tags: web-services, api, video

Is it true that any REST based API to upload videos will always require you to have the video file on your server i.e. it is not possible to pass it directly to that web service?

I am just trying to rule out all the possible APIs that are open to me.

Anyone know of an API I can make use of to upload directly from the users machine so that I don't have to suffer the heavy bandwidth costs? ;)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make form in a web page POST to the rest API endpoint if there was an API that allowed video to be posted - this way it wouldn't end up going to your server unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you think this is possible on Viddler's API: http://developers.viddler.com/documentation/api/method-videos-upload/

Comment: Yep, should be - in fact I think that is the use case they are imagining. Just make a form, set the action to be that URL, with a file upload. Make sure the form type is multipart/form-data, though that's probably going to happen automatically.